# arm9 bootloader IAR

Tags: bootloader, iar, atmel, arm9

I am looking for a bootloader for Atmel Arm9.

Atmel has a "**Safe and secure boot loader**" but that is for a ARM7 and is quite old (does not build using the latest IAR toolchain)

I am assuming that this has to be done before and don't want to reinvent the wheel

Bonus would be if the boot loader is for the Latest IAR Embedded workbench (Version 6.x)

If there is a commercial product available - that would be fine too.

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Atmel ARM9 part you are using, it may already have a bootloader in ROM, I am working with the AT91SAM9RL and the bootloader can be accessed by connecting the BMS pin to VDDIOP at power on. The embedded bootloader can then load application code from SD Card, NAND, SPI DataFlash and Serial or USB (using SAM-BA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I realize that using SAM-BA and ROM-BOOT one can program flash but I was under the impression that you need to have yet another boot loader like AT91Bootstrap that will then copy your application code from Flash to RAM and then run.

When the ROM-BOOT runs - it attempts to find code in flash but does it also copy the code from Flash to RAM - if so what is the purpose of something like the AT91BootStrap.

Pedro

Comment: The ROM bootloader on my particular chip does copy the data to RAM then jumps to it, as for the purpose of AT91BootStrap, I am unsure, I have not found the need to use it yet.

Comment: So what I have found is that the ROM-BOOT is only capable of copying to the on board RAM (SRAM) - if you need to copy to external RAM (SDRAM) - you need yet another level of bootloader - the AT91BootStrap (or something similar) that will copy to the SDRAM

Comment: I have written a boorloader for arm cortex m3 based on the atmels sam7 example, if you need further assistance contact me